# AngularJS: How to use ng-click with scope variable

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angularjs-ng-click

Within the controller I have something like

```
$scope.changeView = function ( path ) 
{
    $location.path( path );
};
```

And from the html page, I have something like

```
<div ng-click="changeView( '/post/{{ post.content_id }}' )">
```

Now, when I view the source it seems to render correctly as

```
<div ng-click="changeView( '/post/4' )">
```

However, when I do the actual click from the browser, it loads the path as `http://foo/#/post/{{ post.content_id }}`, instead of `http://foo/#/post/4`.

What's up with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
<div ng-click="changeView( '/post/'+ post.content_id )">
```

Comment: Yes, just tried that... and it works. However, I am wondering the correct usage of `$location.path( foo ).search( foo )`.

Comment: @Grateful why are using search ?

Comment: It's used for parameters. Anyway. The solution you posted is good enough for now.